# cURL command to create GitHub repository using API not returning response

Tags: git, curl, command-line-interface, repository

I'm trying to use cURL to create a new GitHub repository using their API, but I'm not getting any response from the command. Here's the command I'm using:

```
curl -u "unknown" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"netflix-clone","private":false}'
```

Problem Details:
When I execute the command, it seems to hang indefinitely without providing any output. Even when I try to interrupt the command using Ctrl+C, it just closes without showing any results. I've checked my internet connection, and I'm able to access other websites without any issues.

What I Tried:

1. Verified that the URL (https://api.github.com/user/repos) is correct by testing it in a browser and using a basic cURL command (curl https://api.github.com/user/repos).
2. Double-checked my GitHub credentials and ensured they have the necessary permissions to create repositories.
3. Made sure the JSON data is properly formatted and enclosed in single quotes to prevent any issues with special characters.
4. Increased the timeout using the --connect-timeout option, but this didn't change the behavior.

I expected the cURL command to create a new GitHub repository named "netflix-clone" with public visibility. However, the command seems to hang without returning any response. I anticipated a success message or an error message that would help me understand what's going wrong.

Comment: What do you get by adding `-v` to your curl command?

Comment: hi @JimRedmond i have not tried the "-v" command, how do I try it out?

Comment: It's part of the curl command: `curl -v` and then the rest of it. `-v` in most CLI programs is for "verbose mode".